# Theoretically, if I swish a laser back and forth fast enough/at the right frequency on a distant surface, will I get an interference pattern?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, laser, interference

Just curious. I’m kinda stumped and am interested in how one would go about visualizing/calculating this.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are thinking? What exactly would be interfering with what?

Comment: As in, if the laser was moving fast enough (perpendicular to the beam), would it be able to interfere with itself at different positions?

Comment: How would the light catch up with itself? Think about a house, no matter how fast you move a hose the water won't be able to catch up with water that came out before it. In that way, I'm not sure you can get conventional interference with a laser like this. If there were two lasers, or mirrors,  or materials involved then it would be possible i think.